# Обработка дублей в DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Есть DataFrame содержащий дубли, которые определяются по полю 'ИД':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ИД': ['157411', '159281', '159281', '30980', '30980', '30980', '30980'],
                  'СЗС': ['14.1.1', '15.1.1', '15.1.1', '16.1.3', '16.1.3', '16.1.3', '16.1.3'],
                  'KKS': ['10ABD01GD001', '00CYR02GM203', '00CYR02GM203', '11SAD21AN001', '11SAD21AN001', '11SAD21AN001', '11SAD21AN001'],
                  'Наименование': ['Токопровод', 'Блок', 'Блок', 'Компрессор', 'Компрессор', 'Компрессор', 'Компрессор'],
                  'ВидРаботы': ['Оборудование', 'Оборудование', 'Оборудование', 'Оборудование','Строительная работа', 'Материал', 'Монтажная работа'],
                  'Цена': [100.10, 200.20, 100.30, 200.30, 300.20, 120.10, 120.53]})

df


      ИД     СЗС       KKS         Наименование     ВидРаботы         Цена
0   157411  14.1.1  10ABD01GD001    Токопровод  Оборудование         100.10
1   159281  15.1.1  00CYR02GM203    Блок        Оборудование         200.20
2   159281  15.1.1  00CYR02GM203    Блок        Оборудование         100.30
3   30980   16.1.3  11SAD21AN001    Компрессор  Оборудование         200.30
4   30980   16.1.3  11SAD21AN001    Компрессор  Строительная работа  300.20
5   30980   16.1.3  11SAD21AN001    Компрессор  Материал             120.10
6   30980   16.1.3  11SAD21AN001    Компрессор  Монтажная работа     120.53
```

Надо получить новый DataFrame (к сожалению, не смог воспроизвести его вид в узком окне редактора, по этому ниже привожу код):

```
    ИД         СЗС     KKS          Наименование    ВидРаботы   Цена    equip   mater   mount   constr
0   157411  14.1.1  10ABD01GD001    токопровод     Оборудование     100.10  100.1   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   159281  15.1.1  00CYR02GM203    Блок           Оборудование Оборудование    200.20 100.30   300.5   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   30980   16.1.3  11SAD21AN001    Компрессор     Оборудование Строительная работа Материал М...   200.30 300.20 120.10 120.53     200.3   120.1   120.53  300.2

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'ИД': ['157411', '159281', '30980'],
                  'СЗС': ['14.1.1', '15.1.1',  '16.1.3'],
                  'KKS': ['10ABD01GD001', '00CYR02GM203', '11SAD21AN001'],
                  'Наименование': ['токопровод', 'Блок', 'Компрессор'],
                  'ВидРаботы': ['Оборудование', 'Оборудование  Оборудование', 'Оборудование  Строительная работа  Материал  Монтажная работа'],
                  'Цена': ['100.10', '200.20  100.30', '200.30  300.20  120.10  120.53'], 
                  'equip': [100.10, 300.50, 200.30],
                  'mater': [np.nan, np.nan, 120.10],
                  'mount': [np.nan, np.nan, 120.53],
                  'constr': [np.nan, np.nan, 300.20]
                        })
```

Алгоритм обработки:
По сути, данные из вертикального представления, необходимо трансформировать в горизонтальное, с распределением в соответствующие добавленные колонки. Свертка проводится по полю "ВидРаботы", а стоимость по одинаковым работам (поле " Цена"), суммируется.
Данные в полях "ВидРаботы" и "Цена", после свертки, для сохранения истории, необходимо "склеить", желательно, через перевод строки.

Comment: @MaxU, посмотри пожалуйста эту задачу!

Answer (score 0):

Сначала не смог понять, как принципиально решается данная задача...
Затем "прикинул к носу" и получилось следующее решение:

```
def double_processing(df):
    df_new = pd.DataFrame()
    list_id = list(df['ИД'].unique())
    num_str_in = 0
    num_str_out = 0

    for id in list_id:
        df_temp = df[df['ИД'].isin([id])]
        num_str_in += len(df_temp)
        df_group = df_temp.groupby(['ВидРаботы']).sum()
        list_work = list(df_group.index)
        equip_price = 0
        material_price = 0
        install_work = 0
        constr_work = 0  

        for i, work in enumerate(list_work):
            summ = df_group.iloc[i, 0]
            print(equip_price, material_price, install_work, constr_work)
            if work == 'Оборудование':
                equip_price = summ
            if work == 'Материал':
                material_price = summ
            if work == 'Монтажная работа':
                install_work = summ
            if work == 'Строительная работа':
                constr_work = summ            

        df_row = df_temp.iloc[0].copy(deep=True)
        num_str_out += 1
        df_row[['equip_price', 'material_price', 'install_work', 'constr_work']] = equip_price, material_price, install_work, constr_work

        df_new = df_new.append(df_row, ignore_index=True, sort=None)
        print('Input lines: ', num_str_in)
        print('Output lines: ', num_str_out)
        print('Processing double: ', num_str_in - num_str_out)
    return df_new

df_new = double_processing(df)
```

Спасибо, что дали возможность разобраться самому!!!